# How to display a certain details from database

Tags: php

I have this code for search in mysql and It is working but when I run and entered a account number it display all accounts in my database
I just want to display details for the account number that I inquire on.

what should I change or add? I don't know

```
<?php

echo "<h2>Search Results:</h2><p>";

//If they did not enter a search term we give them an error
if ($find == "Account_Number")
{
echo "<p>You forgot to enter a search term!!!";
exit;
}

// Otherwise we connect to our Database
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("database") or die(mysql_error());

// We perform a bit of filtering
$find = strtoupper($find);
$find = strip_tags($find);
$find = trim ($find);

//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified
$data = mysql_query("SELECT Account_Number, Name, Balance FROM memaccounts WHERE ID    
LIKE'%$find%'");

//And we display the results
while($result = mysql_fetch_array( $data ))
{
echo $result['Account_Number'];
echo " ";
echo $result['Name'];
echo "<br>";
echo $result['Balance'];
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
}


$anymatches=mysql_num_rows($data);
if ($anymatches == 0)
{
echo "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query...<br><br>";
}

//And we remind them what they searched for
echo "<b>Searched For:</b> " .$find;
//} 
?>
```

Comment: change `WHERE ID    
LIKE'%$find%'` to `WHERE ID = '$find'`

Comment: Thank you, I already change it and there is an error "Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query..."

Comment: WHat is the definition of your `ID` field?

Comment: check via PHPMyAdmin that this id exist!

Comment: id exist in my phpmyadmin

Comment: Echo out `$find` and show us what it is just before you use it in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = mysql_query("SELECT Account_Number, Name, Balance FROM
 memaccounts WHERE Account_Number  = '" . trim($find) . "' ");

1.where with Ac no.
```

**Suggestion** : Use mysqli_*

Comment: This is a primary key. So he should use `WHERE Account_Number = '$find'`.

Comment: may user add spacing in textbox!

Comment: @TobiasKun If ID is what we woudl all expect it to be, why are they doing `strtoupper()` , `strip_tags()` and `trim()` on the value before using it in the query. Maybe @BhavinRana has a point here.